# Pytorch Memory Management Issue

Tags: memory-management, pytorch, gpu, gpgpu

For GPU profiling purposes, I ran code to inference pre-trained models provided by PyTorch.
The profiling results showed that a large portion of memory was pre-allocated with zeros, and then only the necessary amount was actually used later on. As a result, there was a significant amount of memory left unused until the process was terminated.
I'm suspicious whether PyTorch's memory management is responsible for this behavior. After all, with pre-trained models, PyTorch should have a precise estimate of how much memory is required. Why does it choose to adopt such a method?

I performed inference using a pre-trained model provided by the PyTorch framework, expecting that only the necessary memory space would be allocated. However, I observed that memory allocation occurred at the beginning, even for memory that wouldn't be used until the end of the process.

Comment: Use the torch profiler and post the results. [link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/profiler_recipe.html), [link](https://pytorch.org/blog/understanding-gpu-memory-1/). Also, how did you determine the "correct" amount of memory required? Remember that you need to account for the activations computed for inference in addition to the weights.